# Let $\mu (X)= \infty $ and $f\in L_1(X)$ and $f\in L_\infty(X)$. Show that $f\in L_p(X)$ for $1<p<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\mu (X)= \infty $ and $f\in L_1(X)$ and $f\in L_\infty(X)$.

Show that $f\in L_p(X)$ for $1<p<\infty$

*$f\in L_p \iff (\int |f|^pd\mu)^{1/p}<\infty $ for  $1\le p<\infty$

**$||f||_p=(\int|f|^pd\mu)^{1/p}$

*$f\in L_\infty \iff f$ is essentially bounded that is $|f(x)|\le||f||_\infty$

** $||f||_\infty=inf\lbrace S(N): N\in \mathcal{X}, \mu(N)=0 \rbrace$ where $S(N)= sup\lbrace |f(x)|: x\notin N \rbrace$

So what I did is following:

We have by Hölder's Inequality (in pirncipal extended) $\int |f|^p d\mu\le ||f||_1.||f^{p-1}||_\infty = ||f||_1.(||f||_\infty)^{p-1} < \infty $

I am doing terribly wrong probably so any help is appreciated

Comment: this looks good. you can also show that if f is L^p and L^q it is L^r for $r\in (p,q)$ with just the same method.

Comment: @mookid Does this valid for any $1\le p,q\le \infty$

Comment: yes it is. {}{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have works.  You're done, because you've shown $\int |f|^p$ is finite, hence $\left\| f\right\|_p$ is finite.

You can also show the same by observing that $|f(x)|^p \le |f(x)|^1 \left( \left\|f\right\|_\infty \right)^{p-1}$.

Comment: this is already in OP's post

Comment: @mookid Yes I suppose it is.  Not sure where OP is confused then.

Comment: $||f^{p-1}||_\infty = (||f||_\infty)^{p-1} $ is the problem can I say this directly

Comment: @user108539 Yes, since $t^{p-1}$ is a strictly increasing function, $\sup_x |f(x)|^{p-1} = \left( \sup_x |f(x)| \right)^{p-1}$.  If you're unconvinced, try showing that each is less than or equal to the other, using the fact that $t^{p-1}$ is strictly increasing.